# In Cryptojs: how does AES generate a key from a passphrase?

Tags: aes, cryptojs, kdf

In CryptoJS's wiki, it states that:

> CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the
> variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase,
> then it will generate a 256-bit key.

That last sentence says if I use a passphrase, "it" will generate a 256-bit key. So my question is: how does the AES function generate the key from the passphrase? Does it use a standard `KDF` like `PBKDF2`? Or does it use a custom `KDF` that only exists in the AES function?

Comment: CryptoJS applies a proprietary key derivation function, namely [`EVP_BytesToKey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) together with an 8 bytes salt, an iteration count of 1 and the digest MD5. This derivation is insecure and should therefore not be used.

Comment: @Topaco why do they do that, when their own library contains a PBKDF2 implementation? Why don't they use PBKDF2?

Comment: It's kind of the OpenSSL default. These kind of "convenience methods" are made by the devil, don't use them. AES - the block cipher - doesn't specify any password based key derivation method (or a default mode or anything like that. Don't confuse the next developer: create a *protocol description* and explicitly implement that.

Comment: Only the developers can answer that. Probably because an [interoperability](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability) with OpenSSL has been originally intended. Newer versions of OpenSSL prefer more reliable derivations and issue a warning (on the command line) when `EVP_BytesToKey()` is used. CryptoJS, however, has stuck with the deprecated derivation (possibly for compatibility reasons). But CryptoJS also supports PBKDF2. An alternative is to explicitly derive the key (and IV) with PBKDF2 and use that key (and IV) for encryption.