Getting Same result for AES encryption and decryption in python and typescript
I am using the below code to encrypt and decrypt in typescript:
const AES = require('crypto-js/aes');
const Utf8 = require('crypto-js/enc-utf8');

export const encrypt = (text, passphrase) => {
  return AES.encrypt(text, passphrase).toString();
};

export const decrypt = (ciphertext, passphrase) => {
  const bytes = AES.decrypt(ciphertext, passphrase);
  const originalText = bytes.toString(Utf8);
  return originalText;
};

Now, the encrypted message generated in Typescript is to be decrypted in a Python environment. I used Chat GPT to come up with a solution but it gave a different result.
In one of the StackOverflow answers it was mentioned that CryptoJS uses following method for AES encryption:

Now CryptoJs derives a 32 byte long encryption key for AES-256 and a
16 byte long initialization vector (iv) from the password, encrypts
the "Message" using this key, iv in AES mode CBC and (default) padding
Pkcs7.

I gave the above details as context to Chat GPT but that didn't work either. My Python code uses cryptography library and the code looks like below.
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.scrypt import Scrypt
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from os import urandom

def derive_key_iv(password: str, salt: bytes, key_length=32, iv_length=16):
    # Key derivation function
    backend = default_backend()
    kdf = Scrypt(
        salt=salt,
        length=key_length + iv_length,
        n=2**14,
        r=8,
        p=1,
        backend=backend
    )
    key_iv = kdf.derive(password.encode())
    return key_iv[:key_length], key_iv[key_length:key_length+iv_length]

def encrypt(message: str, password: str):
    salt = urandom(16)  # Generate a random salt
    key, iv = derive_key_iv(password, salt)
    backend = default_backend()
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    padded_data = padder.update(message.encode()) + padder.finalize()
    encrypted = encryptor.update(padded_data) + encryptor.finalize()
    return salt + encrypted  # prepend salt for use in decryption

def decrypt(token: bytes, password: str):
    salt = token[:16]  # Extract the salt from the beginning
    encrypted_message = token[16:]
    key, iv = derive_key_iv(password, salt)
    backend = default_backend()
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    padded_plaintext = decryptor.update(encrypted_message) + decryptor.finalize()
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()
    plaintext = unpadder.update(padded_plaintext) + unpadder.finalize()
    return plaintext.decode()

What can be done to get the correct decrypted result in python?

These previous questions address the same or relevant issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67837825/238704, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65569267/238704, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74833011/238704, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74381627/238704

You have to fix the following things in the Python code to make it compatible with the CryptoJS code: 1. use the key derivation function EVP_BytesToKey() (with an iteration count of 1 and MD5 as digest) instead of Scrypt(), 2. apply an 8 bytes salt instead of a 16 bytes salt and 3. return the result in the Base64 encoded OpenSSL format (= ASCII encoding of Salted__ plus salt plus ciphertext) during encryption (salt and ciphertext have to be extracted accordingly during decryption).
